# Actionbar and Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an actionbar with a button on the left, a logo in the center and another button on the right. However, whenever I launch a new intent or activity, the whole actionbar "refresh".

I understand that I need to use Fragments. However, how do I go about implementing that? I saw a lot of examples are fragments with tabs. But I just want my actionbar to remain fixed as I move from one activity to another. I do not have any tabs at all.

Can you please give me examples on how do I go about implementing it? If I have activity A and B. Does that mean I should have 2 fragments?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have only 1 action-bar for all activities you will create a `FragmentActivity` class in which you will display Fragments. Only this `FragmentActivity` will have a action bar.

You can add, remove, replace Fragments in its(FragmentActivity's) body and change it when you want, like this

```
  FragmentManager fmu = getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction transaction = fmu.beginTransaction();
  transaction.replace(R.id.realViewSwitcher_body, English.newInstance()).commit();
```

Here `realViewSwitcher_body` is initial View present in `FragmentActivity` a I replaced it with a Fragment (`English.newInstance()` its a method with is returning a fragment instance)

This is the whole Scenario either you use Tabs or View-Pager etc and up to my knowledge and experience you can not use Intents for activities having only one Action-bar.

Comment: Do i place this in OnCreate method? So in this case realViewSwitcher_body is the layout for one "activity" (or intent) and English.newInstance() is the fragment for another "activity" (or intent)?
And another thing, how do I pass data from one fragment to another?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `Fragment` can be place into a layout or `FrameLayout`. All you need to do is create an instance of Fragment then use `FragmentTransaction` that you get from `FragmentActivity` as you normally would.